# Suggest for edits with approval on demand

Tags: discussion, edits, privileges

When you at last achieved to have the privilege of **Edit Questions And Answers** shouldn't be there the possibility for at least the author approve your edits?

Let me elaborate.

You read a block of text describing that is the situation and with embedded questions and all these in paragraph what is quite unclear for the community and future reading or using as reference in similar issues.

Of course, you have the ability to **completely modify** the question with the danger of changing the authors asking intention, which is also not the point of editing privilege.

So, it may be more helpful to can do such a suggestion for more clear questions / answers and also `request` for approval of the author about what he is really asking.

Comment: Comment asking for clarification / Edit -> Ask OP to rollback if edit was invalid -> Rollback if necessary

Comment: So you mean that just edit the question and comment to the author to rollback if the meaning is changed?